# prevent input string or integer value php

Tags: php

I have a question about to writing a php code which prevent to input string or integer

let say I'm waiting for user input which should be a string.

> example
>
> please Enter todays date :  $date

and I write a code to prevent input integer.

```
if($edate== NULL || !_string($edate){

close
}
```

but if I do the input as  $date = 2013-10-3.
is it read this input as string or integer?? I thought its read as string 
but when I was input $date = 2013-10-3. it goes to the if loop.

1. is 2013-10-3 consider as string or integer?
2. How do I write a code to qualify this tern desired

and i used  !is_int($response) || !is_int($visibility) to prevent user input 
string value for response and visibility but even though I input the integer
it goes to this loop and close the program

Comment: Where does `$edate` come from? And what's `_string()`?

Comment: and how do you get the user input. CLI or $_GET/$_POST?

Comment: Do you mean `is_string`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a string of course.

If you use the [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) class, and provide and invalid date, an exception will be thrown - you are safe to check then.

Comment: `2013-10-3` can be int as well (2000) ;)

Comment: Yea that is what i thought. but code closed when i input a string value

Comment: !is_int($response) || !is_int($visibility) , and for this even though i input both integer , it goes to this loop and close the program..wt